# Laravel One to Many relationship not working - returns recursion

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-jetstream

I am developing an application with Laravel 8 and I ran into very strange behavior.

I have a Model called "Organisation", this Organisation has many Users (Model from Jetstream).

I did the relationship as usual:

In  Organisation Model:

```
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
```

In User Model:

```
 public function organisation()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Organisation::class);
    }
```

I have a field on the users table called organisation_id which is declared in the migration as such:

```
 $table->foreignId('organisation_id')->nullable()->constrained();
```

I checked the DB, everything is filled in, with no null values.

**Expected result:**
If I call

```
  $testUser=User::find(1);
  $testOrg=$testUser->organisation();
```

I will get the organization object.

**Actual result:**
I receive a veeeeery log object, stating something including *RECURSION*, instead of the organization I want. Is this an error regarding the foreign key? The User model also has a belongsToMany Relationship to a different model, is this in the way of the standard belongsTo?

**EDIT**
I can receive the organization when calling

```
  $testUser=User::with('organisation')->find(1);
```

But this is not the clean Laravel way I want to work with.

I debugged the query with $testOrg=$testUser->organisation()->toSql();
and it displayed me:
string(60) "select * from `organisations` where `organisations`.`id` = ?" ,

So the "where" is wrong?

Any hints or help would be very appreciated

Here is some of the output: (whole output is too long)

> NULL ["remember_token"]=> NULL ["current_team_id"]=> NULL
> ["profile_photo_path"]=> NULL ["created_at"]=> NULL ["updated_at"]=>
> NULL ["organisation_id"]=> int(1) } ["changes":protected]=> array(0) {
> } ["classCastCache":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dates":protected]=>
> array(0) { } ["dateFormat":protected]=> NULL
> ["dispatchesEvents":protected]=> array(0) { }
> ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["relations":protected]=>
> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["timestamps"]=>
> bool(true) ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { }
> ["guarded":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" }
> ["rememberTokenName":protected]=> string(14) "remember_token"
> ["accessToken":protected]=> NULL } ["foreignKey":protected]=>
> string(15) "organisation_id" ["ownerKey":protected]=> string(2) "id"
> ["relationName":protected]=> string(12) "organisation"
> ["query":protected]=>
> object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder)#1386 (8) {
> ["query":protected]=> object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder)#1388
> (22) { ["connection"]=>
> object(Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection)#1353 (18) {
> ["pdo":protected]=> object(PDO)#1364 (0) { } ["readPdo":protected]=>
> NULL ["database":protected]=> string(7) "laravel"
> ["tablePrefix":protected]=> string(0) "" ["config":protected]=>
> array(15) { ["driver"]=> string(5) "mysql" ["host"]=> string(9)
> "127.0.0.1" ["port"]=> string(4) "3306" ["database"]=> string(7)
> "laravel" ["username"]=> string(4) "root" ["password"]=> string(0) ""
> ["unix_socket"]=> string(0) "" ["charset"]=> string(7) "utf8mb4"
> ["collation"]=> string(18) "utf8mb4_unicode_ci" ["prefix"]=> string(0)
> "" ["prefix_indexes"]=> bool(true) ["strict"]=> bool(true)
> ["engine"]=> NULL ["options"]=> array(0) { } ["name"]=> string(5)
> "mysql" } ["reconnector":protected]=> object(Closure)#132 (2) {
> ["this"]=> object(Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager)#40 (5) {
> ["app":protected]=> object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application)#2 (35) {
> ["basePath":protected]=> string(38)
> "C:\xampp\htdocs\wiederverkaufen-portal"
> ["hasBeenBootstrapped":protected]=> bool(true) ["booted":protected]=>
> bool(true) ["bootingCallbacks":protected]=> array(2) { [0]=>
> object(Closure)#195 (2) { ["static"]=> array(1) { ["instance"]=>
> object(Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider)#189 (3) {
> ["app":protected]=> *RECURSION* ["bootingCallbacks":protected]=>
> array(0) { } ["bootedCallbacks":protected]=> array(0) { } } }
> ["this"]=> *RECURSION* } [1]=> object(Closure)#338 (2) { ["static"]=>
> array(1) { ["instance"]=>
> object(Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider)#332 (3) {
> ["app":protected]=> *RECURSION* ["bootingCallbacks":protected]=>
> array(0) { } ["bootedCallbacks":protected]=> array(0) { } } }
> ["this"]=> *RECURSION* } } ["bootedCallbacks":protected]=> array(1) {
> [0]=> object(Closure)#340 (1) { ["this"]=>
> object(App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider)#164 (5) {
> ["namespace":protected]=> NULL ["loadRoutesUsing":protected]=>
> object(Closure)#341 (1) { ["this"]=> *RECURSION* } ["app":protected]=>
> *RECURSION* ["bootingCallbacks":protected]=> array(0) { } ["bootedCallbacks":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(Closure)#165
> (1) { ["this"]=> *RECURSION* } } } } }
> ["terminatingCallbacks":protected]=> array(0) { }
> ["serviceProviders":protected]=> array(34) { [0]=>
> object(Illuminate\Events\EventServiceProvider)#6 (3) {
> ["app":protected]=> *RECURSION* ["bootingCallbacks":protected]=>
> array(0) { } ["bootedCallbacks":protected]=> array(0) { } } [1]=>
> object(Illuminate\Log\LogServiceProvider)#8 (3) { ["app":protected]=>
> *RECURSION*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $testUser=User::with('organisation')->find(1);
```

If you want to continue your way then update to this:

```
$testUser=User::find(1);
$testOrg=$testUser->organisation;
```

Comment: This does work, I get the organisation. But shouldn't it work by just calling $testUser->organisation() ?

Comment: No, it will not work this way try using laravel eager loading which is best way of doing it according to laravel documentation.

Comment: But in the Laravel documentation, you can easily access the parent of the belongsTo relationship, like I did here, :
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse

Comment: You have made a mistake update organisation() to organisation. Just remove the brackets.

Comment: OMG, thank you so much, that was indeed the problem, forgive my stupidity :/

Comment: No problem, I am glad to help you.